# Slideshow with Pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm having issues where the previous images will flash while the sprite gets drawn on the screen.

I need this to look smooth and if possible i also need the images centered. To do that i was thinking of taking the fullscreen resolution and subtracting half of image width from half of the screen resolution width to come up with where to place the image on the x axis. Any problems with that theory?

```
import argparse
import random
import os

import pyglet



def update_image(dt):
    global count
    try:
    count
    except:
    count=0
    img = pyglet.image.load(image_paths[count])
    sprite.image = img
    sprite.scale = get_scale(window, img)
##    sprite.x = 0
##    sprite.y = 0
    if count ==len(image_paths)-1:
    count=0
    else:
    count+=1
    window.clear()


def get_image_paths(input_dir='.'):
    paths = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir, topdown=True):
    for file in sorted(files):
        if file.endswith(('jpg', 'png', 'gif')):
        path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
        paths.append(path)
    return paths


def get_scale(window, image):
    if image.width > image.height:
    scale = float(window.width) / image.width
    else:
    scale = float(window.height) / image.height
    return scale

global window
window = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen=True)


@window.event
def on_draw():
    sprite.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global count
    try:
    count
    except:
    count=0
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('dir', help='directory of images',
            nargs='?', default=os.getcwd()+'\\slides')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    global image_paths
    image_paths = get_image_paths(args.dir)
    img = pyglet.image.load(image_paths[count])
    sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img)
    sprite.scale = get_scale(window, img) 

    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update_image, 2.0)


    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Why are you clearing the window in the update function? The idea of centering (along the x axis) seems to be correct.

Comment: haha because i needed to but i put it at the end instead of the beginning.

Comment: You should probably put it first in `on_draw`.